# How can I access GDEF / GPOS / GSUB of a ttf font (not a otf)?

Tags: c++, windows, truetype, freetype, freetype2

One main question, several underwritten questions (sorry).

I'm trying to read GSUB infos (and other tables) in a ttf font. How to do that? Which lib could I use?

*GSUB is a substitution table telling how glyphs used in the same neighborhood must morph to another glyph. Is is very common in many languages, and in english, it is more rare, but the best example is ligature.*

It is good documented for [OpenType fonts (otf)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/typography/opentype/spec/gsub) and I know it exists in Truetype fonts (ttf).

But how can I access it? Is there a library such as Freetype + Harfbuzz? 
It seems Freetype gives only access to OTF tables, not TTF, am I right?

`FT_OpenType_Validate`: *This function only works with OpenType fonts*

And is Harfbuzz optional or mandatory for such needs?

Documentations are poor (at my pov), so I'm searching for experiences, working examples.

It also seems to be hard to make freetype + harfbuzz working toghether on windows, is it really needed? How to?

Sources:

[mactype](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype/blob/d895921decdf565d64fc5e3b7f94c700c4fe78e4/ft2vert.c)

[official poor example](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/example5.cpp)

My test code, not working, because GSUB is an "Unimplemented Feature" says Freetype:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include FT_OPENTYPE_VALIDATE_H

#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FT_Library ftLibrary;

    FT_Error errorLib = FT_Init_FreeType(&ftLibrary);
    if (errorLib)
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't initialize the library: FT_Init_FreeType() failed");

    FT_Face ftFace;

    FT_Error errorFace = FT_New_Face(ftLibrary, argv[1], 0, &ftFace); //getting first face
    if (errorFace)
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't load the font file: FT_New_Face() failed");

    FT_Bytes BASE = NULL;
    FT_Bytes GDEF = NULL;
    FT_Bytes GPOS = NULL;
    FT_Bytes GSUB = NULL;
    FT_Bytes JSTF = NULL;

    FT_Error errorValidate = FT_OpenType_Validate(ftFace, FT_VALIDATE_GSUB, &BASE, &GDEF, &GPOS, &GSUB, &JSTF);
    if (errorValidate)
        throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't validate opentype datas");
    //7=Unimplemented_Feature

    FT_OpenType_Free(ftFace, BASE);
    FT_OpenType_Free(ftFace, GDEF);
    FT_OpenType_Free(ftFace, GPOS);
    FT_OpenType_Free(ftFace, GSUB);
    FT_OpenType_Free(ftFace, JSTF);

    FT_Done_Face(ftFace);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ftLibrary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fear this is going to be difficult. First, I beg your pardon to answer quickly from 15+-year-old memory. OpenType 1.0 came out about at the same time as Freetype 2, and developed in parallel for several years. Freetype-1.4 had support for your need, for example, but that part were not integrated into FT2. When OT *stabilized* at 1.4, its support was added correctly to FT2 for the full OTF fonts (as Adobe and MS wanted), but the effort to deal with each and every TT+OT font out there was not invested.

Comment: While searching for the reference of the assertion above, I found a message from Werner [this about (May 2000)](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/freetype-devel/2000-05/msg00004.html). I have no idea if it could be possible to get back to Freetype 1 in 2018 (certainly not easy: this is C code ported from Pascal written in 1996, not updated for almost 20 years; and the API is not one bit nice compared to FT2).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you have to enable OpenType Validation Module. If you're using Visual Studio to build FreeType then follow steps below.

In `freetype/config/ftmodule.h` add this:

```cpp
FT_USE_MODULE( FT_Module_Class, otv_module_class )
```

Then in Solution Explorer add `src/otvalid/otvalid.c` to the project.

You are ready to build library. Don't forget to update your project with new library or object files.

Using this I was able to get access to `GPOS` table. But don't be very optimistic. OpenType's tables support in FreeType is super limited. So, what you really get is raw pointer to bytes. In order to get some useful data there you have to parse these bytes according to OpenType spec. And I would say that this is not a trivial task taking into account complexity of the OpenType spec. I would even say that it's overcomplicated, but still possible.

If you decide to do it remember that you have to reverse byte order for data that you read from any table.